# Perl 6 - Subroutine taking "Bareword" input

Tags: perl, parsing, declaration, raku

So I've been diving into Perl 6 and have been looking at interpreting another language using Perl 6's operator definitions. I understand that this could be done by parsing the code but I'm looking to push Perl 6's capabilities to see what it can do. Having this functionality would also make the parsing a lot easier

I'm trying to make a variable definition in a C-style format.(The language isn't important)

Something like:

```
char foo;
```

Where the **char** represents the type and the foo is the variable name. From my understanding the **char** can be interpreted using an operator definition like so:

```
sub prefix:<char>($input) {
    say $input;
}
```

Which calls a subroutine with the **foo** as **$input**. The idea from here would be to use **foo** as a string and hold it's reference in a hash somewhere. The problem with this is that Perl 6 seems to see any bareword as a function call and will complain when it can't find the "Undeclared routine".

I've looked possibly everywhere for an answer to this and the only thing that makes me still think that this may be possible is the **qw** function from Perl 5 which is now **< >** in Perl 6. The **< >** is obviously an operator which leads me to believe that there is a subroutine defined somewhere that tells this operator how to work and how to deal with the bareword input.

So to my question:

Is there a way of accepting bareword input into a subroutine just like the **< >** operator does?

Cheers!

Comment: `<>` isn't necessarily an operator that takes barewords, it could be defined as part of the grammar. Perhaps instead of defining a function, you need to [add to the grammar](http://doc.perl6.org/language/grammars)?

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that there is a `circumfix` keyword to define surrounding operators. But you won't get the barewords passed to it. In that instance, you might have to delve into macros, as Schwern pointed out.

Comment: as Schwern suggested, ony way to do it is by introducing a new 'slang'; take a look at [Slang::SQL](https://github.com/tony-o/perl6-slang-sql/)

Comment: Thanks Guys, looks like Slangs are the way to go with this one so thanks for directing me in the right direction. Only problem being that there isn't much explanation on this concept anywhere. I found this https://mouq.github.io/slangs.html which was kind of useful but with the explanation lacking mid way through I found myself lost again. I've seemed to find Grammar explanations that are decent enough and Slang examples that are too much too fast, there's no in between. Anyone have any resources that are a bit easier to follow?

Comment: Actually you should be able to do this with a macro. Unfortunately Macros are going to be a post-christmas thing.

Comment: @Phyreprooph Have you mostly put this to one side for now or would a belated answer still be especially helpful to you? If the latter, please comment here about exactly where you first found/find mouq's document confusing, and let me know if you've since seen any other helpful posts about slangs.

Comment: This was more of a curiosity thing than a, not being able to continue without it thing. For now I've put it aside but feel free to answer. There might not be many good grammar/whatever explanations out there but I wouldn't know as I haven't looked further into it.

Comment: I'd take a look at any of the Slang code from modules.perl6.org also my own one which adds a new quoted-literal constructor lives here: https://github.com/MattOates/BioInfo/blob/master/lib/BioInfo.pm6

Comment: Any bareword? Or just a couple of well defined ones? In the latter case you could use sigil-less "variables" to just make it look like barewords.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do that would be to create a [Grammar](https://docs.perl6.org/language/grammar_tutorial) that parses your language. If you additionally want it to run the DSL you have just created, combine it with [Actions](https://docs.perl6.org/language/grammar_tutorial#Grammar_Actions).